# Game black screen that block others windows when alt tab

Tags: windows-10

This is happening like a pattern, meaning that it away happen, and if I got myself into, I cannot get out. Restart with hardware button is the only option.

If I have game (require heavy graphic like Dota 2, ... ) at full screen, and I somehow cause the game to hang, it shown black screen.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, I can see the task bar.

Ctrl-alt-del can turn on Task Manager. I want to turn on task manager. But somehow the "black screen" block everything is not the taskbar. So, I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, I can see the "preview" of windows. I can switch to task manager. However I cannot force the task manger to be on front (the black screen just cover task manager).

I just need to force kill the game. So I need task manger. The problem, said above, task manager stay behind the black full-screen game.

Comment: Try in the Task Manager menu *Options > Always on top* before starting the game.

Comment: Also try Ctrl/Shift/Esc to get *directly* to the Task Manager rather than have to go through any intermediate step.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you could try:

1. As Tetsujin mentioned, set your task manager to always on top in the Options menu, then when you get stuck, you can invoke it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>. If you're sure task manager is open already and you forgot to do it beforehand, you can "blindly" set this option by hitting <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to navigate the menu even if you can't see it.
2. Call up task view by hitting <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>, and opening a new desktop.